# Imprimir elementos de uma matriz em C++

Tags: c

Estou tentando imprimir os elementos da matriz frutas dentro de um `for`, mas o código não está funcionando. Onde estou errando?

```
int main()
{
    char frutas[20][4] = {
                            "Açaí",
                            "Acerola",
                            "Abacate",
                            "Abacaxi",
                            "Ameixa"
                         };

    int size_elements = sizeof(frutas[0]);
    int i;

    printf("Total Elementos Matriz: %d\n", size_elements);

    for(i = 0; i<size_elements; i++){
        printf("%c\n", frutas[i]);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O tamanho definido para a matriz `frutas` não está correto:

```
char frutas[20][4]
```

Primeiramente especificou `4` quando tem `5` frutas. E para alem disso está invertido e deveria ser:

```
char frutas[5][20]
```

Vale lembrar que é um array de `strings` logo primeiro vem a quantidade de strings e só depois o tamanho de cada uma.

Tendo em conta esta diferença o `sizeof` que tem para calcular o tamanho também não é valido:

```
int size_elements = sizeof(frutas[0]);
```

Ao invés disso pode agora pegar no tamanho da matriz toda e dividir pela quantidade de letras que todas elas tem:

```
int size_elements = sizeof(frutas)/20;
```

Por fim se pretende no `for` mostrar strings então deve utilizar `%s`.

Veja o código com essas alterações:

```
int main()
{
    char frutas[5][20] = {
    /*----------^---^ */    "Açaí",
                            "Acerola",
                            "Abacate",
                            "Abacaxi",
                            "Ameixa"
                         };

    int size_elements = sizeof(frutas)/20; //<-- divide por o tamanho de todas as strings
    int i;

    printf("Total Elementos Matriz: %d\n", size_elements);

    for(i = 0; i< size_elements /*<--agora size elements*/; i++){
        printf("%s\n", frutas[i]);
        //-------^ agora %s
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Veja também a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/2HQDim)

Comment: Obrigada Isac. Ficou perfeito!!!